# nginx rewrite to no query string url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

when access url with query string, I want to rewrite to no query string url, like:

```
/blog/(\d+)/(w+)?a=1$b=2....
```

rewrite to

```
/blog/(\d+)/(w+)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to rewrite all requests a query string, just simply add these to your server block.

```
if ($query_string != "") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? last;
}
```

**Explain**

The syntax of rewrite directive is

```
rewrite regex replacement [flag];
```

First the `if` statement will match all requests with query strings and rewrite them with the replacement `$uri?`

According to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), the query strings are dropped because

> If a *replacement* string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, **putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended.**

Finally the `last` flag tells nginx to

> stop processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;